# Django 2.2 set ModelChoiceField initial value without id/pk

Tags: django

I have a GET based search, passing a few search terms and paging info through the query string. I can grab the items from the query string without any issues, but passing them back to the template via the SearchForm to preserve the search is proving to be difficult.

`items/?search=foo&category=bar&page=1&pageSize=20`

***forms.py***

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(*)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Items.objects.all(), *)
```

**simplified for brevity*

In the view, I can retrieve all the values or their defaults from the query string, and I can even set the value for the search field, but the ModelChoiceField is the one I am struggling with. I can set an initial value, but not based on the select text...

***views.py***

```
class ItemList(View):
    template_name = 'items.html'

    def get(self, request):
        items = Item.objects.all()
        form = SearchForm()

        search = request.GET.get('search')
        category = request.GET.get('category')
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
        pageSize = int(request.GET.get('pageSize', 20))

        if category != None:
            #non working:
            #form.fields['category'].initial = category

            #working by setting a value 
            form.fields['category'].initial = 1

            items.filter(category__name=category)

        if search != None:
            form.initial['search'] = search
            items = items.filter(field__icontains=search)

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'items': items
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I tried various methods of trying to retrieve the value/id from the form.category field unsuccessfully. I would hate to have to make a second call to the database to get the categories, and then pull the id from that query, but that seems to be the only thing?

I don't know if I should maybe add the page and pageSize fields to SearchForm and then suppress their display somehow, but my attempts at that haven't been successful, ie:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Items.objects.all())
    page = forms.IntegerField()
    pageSize = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['search', 'category']
```

```
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        #never executes
```

*page and pageSize are still are displayed as fields to the user in this example*

I have tried various solutions using the `__init__` constructor to set the initial values without success as well.

Would appreciate a nudge in the right direction, especially without leveraging the ListView CBV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to not make a trip back to the database using the [to_field_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) attribute. Which contradictory to its name, sets the value attribute for the `<option>` tag.

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), *)
```

results in the html:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control w100 " id="id_category">
  <option value="" selected>Category</option>
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

so when trying to assign the initial value in the views method via:

```
form.fields['category'].initial = category #where category='Category 1'
```

it's trying to compare the `value=1` to `category` and coming up blank.

***solution:***
Adding `to_field_name=` attribute to the `SearchForm` field declaration:

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), to_field_name='name', *)
```

results in the html:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control w100 " id="id_category">
  <option value="" selected>Category</option>
  <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

Making the `form.fields['category'].initial = category` compare the `value="Category 1"` to `category`